# JTS difference op followed by an intersection op not returning expected results

Tags: jts-topology-suite

I have two overlapping polygons and I want to get the line segment(s) where the edges cross.

[image]

So I begin by performing a Difference operation. That gives me the area where A is "outside" of B.

[image]

Then I do an Intersection op. I expect that to give me the line segment where the two polygons "touch", but as you can see I get a smaller than expected result that doesn't extend along the entire edge where they touch. You can see in the above shot where the green result is, but here it is isolated from the two polygons.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to go about this?